# emacs shell vs eshell : sshpass command

Tags: shell, emacs

I execute the same command in emacs shell and eshell

sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no   username@host 'pwd'

eshell give me the correct result,
shell do not give me anything.
could someone explain the reason ?

Comment: First of all, do you understand [conceptual difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104327/99066) between `eshell` and `shell` packages in Emacs? Just in case: reading `C-h P <package-name>` might be a good starting point.

Comment: I tried, could not get the answer.

Comment: I don't have or use `sshpass` but https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass suggests to me that you should run `echo $?` in the shell immediately after the failed attempt, and cross-reference that value (presumably non-zero) with the documented return values.

Comment: N.b. It also advises against using `-p <password>` at all.